# PHP alert box upon $error not working. Possible syntax error?

Tags: javascript, php, syntax-error

I want my error message displayed in an alert box when the form is null. I'm not familiar with PHP. I posted about this last night getting the contact form working and thanks to everyone here I got it working but ran into one final problem.

```
 <?php 
 $errors = '';
 $myemail = 'example@gmail.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
 if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
    empty($_POST['email']) || 
    empty($_POST['phone']))
 {
  $errors .= echo 'alert("Error: all fields are required")';
 }
```

not sure if i can combine the variable with .= echo 'alert'

Comment: Shouldn’t that just be `echo $errors . 'alert("Error: all fields are required")';`?

Comment: or simply echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Error: all fields are required");</script>';

Comment: It works that way however, there is no alert box, it sends me to a completely new page. I'm thinking I need to wrap it in a script with a js alert. not sure how i would do that though.

Comment: @jakub wrona, thank you! That did indeed work and was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change it to the following:-

```
<?php 
 $errors = '';
 $myemail = '3dart.nick@gmail.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
 if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
    empty($_POST['email']) || 
    empty($_POST['phone']))
 {
  echo '<script>alert("Error: all fields are required");</script>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**echo** is used to ouput a string. And it return void type.

```
void echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] );
```

So, in your code remove the $error .=

Juste you use : `echo 'alert("Error: all fields are required")';`

But, to run the alert function at the client browser try like this ; make it into `<script></script>` :

```
echo "<script>alert('Error: all fields are required')</script>";
```

This is the url php manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php